# The getter 'username' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

The getter 'username' was called on null.

```
 class Register extends StatefulWidget {

 final User user;
 Register({this.user});

 @override
 RegisterState createState() => RegisterState();
}


class RegisterState extends State<Register> {
final User user;
RegisterState({this.user});

FirestoreService fireServ = new FirestoreService();

TextEditingController _userNameController;
TextEditingController _userEmailController;
TextEditingController _userPasswordController;
TextEditingController _userMobileController;
TextEditingController _userLocationController;
TextEditingController _userBdController;



@override
 void initState() {
super.initState();
_userNameController = new TextEditingController(text:     '     ${this.user.username}');
_userEmailController = new TextEditingController(text: widget.user.useremail);
_userPasswordController = new TextEditingController(text: widget.user.userpassword);
_userMobileController = new TextEditingController(text: widget.user.usermobile);
_userLocationController = new TextEditingController(text: widget.user.userlcation);
_userBdController = new TextEditingController(text: widget.user.userbd);
```

}

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

 createData() {
 fireServ.createUserList(_userNameController.text,    _userEmailController.text, _userPasswordController.text, _userMobileController.text, _userLocationController.text, _userBdController.text).then((_) {
  Navigator.pop(context);
});
```

}

```
void signUp() async {
if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
  formKey.currentState.save();
  try {
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _userEmailController.text,
            password: _userPasswordController.text)
        .then((signedUser) {
      createData();
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.message);
  }
}
```

}

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // TODO: implement build
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('RegisterPage'),
  ),
  body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      child: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: loginCard() + SocialMedia(),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],)
);
```

}

```
List<Widget> loginCard() {
  return [
   Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 330.0,
                  height: 500.0,
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.1),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          offset: Offset(2, 3),
                          blurRadius: 10,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 40, right: 15),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'Register',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30),
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: _userNameController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'name',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.person,
                                size: 25,
                              ),
                              hintText: 'your name here',
                              hintStyle:
                                  Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                            validator: (value)=>value.isEmpty?'Name can\'t be embty':null,
                            onSaved: (value) => _userNameController.text = value,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: _userEmailController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'email',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.email,
                                size: 25,
                              ),
                              hintText: 'your email here',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 10),
                            ),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                            enableInteractiveSelection: true,
                            validator: (value)=>value.isEmpty?'Email can\'t be embty':null,
                            onSaved: (value) => _userEmailController.text = value,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: _userPasswordController,
                            obscureText: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'password',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.lock,
                                size: 23,
                              ),
                              hintText: 'your password here',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 10),
                            ),
                            validator: (value)=>value.isEmpty?'Password can\'t be embty':null,
                            onSaved: (value) => _userPasswordController.text = value,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: _userMobileController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Mobile Number',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.lock,
                                size: 23,
                              ),
                              hintText: 'your number here',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 10),
                            ),
                            validator: (value)=>value.isEmpty?'Mobile can\'t be embty':null,
                            onSaved: (value) => _userMobileController.text = value,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: _userLocationController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Location',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.lock,
                                size: 23,
                              ),
                              hintText: 'your Location here',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 10),
                            ),
                            validator: (value)=>value.isEmpty?'Location can\'t be embty':null,
                            onSaved: (value) => _userLocationController.text = value,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: _userBdController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Birthday',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.lock,
                                size: 23,
                              ),
                              hintText: 'your number here',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 10),
                            ),
                            validator: (value)=>value.isEmpty?'Mobile can\'t be embty':null,
                            onSaved: (value) => _userBdController.text = value,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 205, top: 10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Sign Up',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  color: Colors.orange,
                                  onPressed: () => signUp(),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
];
```

}

Main Page

```
 void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(

 home: MyApp(),

 ));


 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {



  @override

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return MaterialApp(
  theme: basicTheme(),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Navigation',
  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    '/Login': (BuildContext context) => Login(),
    '/Register': (BuildContext context) => Register(),
    '/Profile': (BuildContext context) => Profile(),
    '/carsPage': (BuildContext context) => carsPage(),
    '/MyAppBar': (BuildContext context) => MyAppBar(),
    '/EditProfile': (BuildContext dynamic) => EditProfile01(),
    '/GarageitemPage': (BuildContext context) => GarageitemPage(),
    '/CarItemPage': (BuildContext context) => CarItemPage(),
    '/washPagePage': (BuildContext context) => washPage(),
    '/reviewsPage': (BuildContext context) => reviewsPage(),
    '/WashItemPage': (BuildContext context) => WashItemPage(),
    '/AddGarageAds': (BuildContext context) => AddGarageAds(),
    '/garagePage': (BuildContext context) => garagePage(),
    '/AddGarageAdsFirebase': (BuildContext context) => AddGarageAdsFirebase(),
   },
   home: Login(),
  );
  }
 }
```

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:
The getter 'username' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: username

User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///Users/ebroo/IdeaProjects/car_app_firebase_03/lib/main.dart:44:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

0 Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)

1 RegisterState.initState (package:car_app_firebase_03/ui_test/register_page.dart:37:72)

2 StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4061:58)

3 ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3912:5)

4 Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3094:14)

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only place where I see you calling `username` on an object is in `_userNameController = new TextEditingController(text:     '     ${this.user.username}')`, so it looks like `this.user` is null.

If that is indeed the cause, you may want to try `${this.user?.username}`, which ensures `.username` doesn't get evaluated if `this.user` is null.

Comment: its should be null because in this field I should give it the parameter in register page ui,

Comment: thanks , I already upvote this answer but am new so it will not appear as they told me ,

Comment: I've question but I don't know how to ask it , I hope you will understand me , when I signed in how to appear specific data for the user who signed in , like his profile , his favorite list ?

Comment: You'll typically store data for each user in the database, under that user's UID. Then you can read that data back from the database when needed. But it's hard to answer in Stack Overflow, so I'd recommend searching for a tutorial on using your preferred database with Flutter. For example: https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+flutter+database+tutorial

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view from the code that you provide, it's look like you didn't pass anything to your **Register** class which lead to null pointer.

you can do something like
**Register(User();**

one more thing, you can add @required for your constructor that can help your compiler to check the error
Register({@required this.user});